# cross-browser transparency - works in everything but ie 10

Tags: css, cross-browser, transparency, internet-explorer-10

I'm using the following code, which will look familiar to just about anyone who's had to make a background transparent, but not the children's, across multiple browsers. It's for one of the base wrappers on my site.

```
div#all { 
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255); /* fallback for web browsers that don't support RGBa */
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0); /* RGBa with 0.0 opacity */
    /* for ie */
    background: transparent\9; /* for ie - resetting background color hack */
    zoom:1; /* for ie - required for the filters */
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF, endColorstr=#00FFFFFF); /* for ie 5.5 - 7 */
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF, endColorstr=#00FFFFFF)"; /* for ie 8 */
}
```

Problem is, it works great right up 'til Win8/IE10 (IE 10 standard only. "IE 10 desktop" is fine). IE 10 shows the site as one solid white block. If I remove the following, IE 10 works, but older versions of IE break.

```
background: transparent\9; /* for ie - resetting background color hack */
```

Since IE 10 ignores conditional statements, how does one get around this?

For the reference, i'm pretty good at php/css/html, but my javascript/jquery aren't so hot, so if that's the solution please be detailed.  My site is www.waterutilitymanagementservices.com

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Completely transparent white on both color stops?  Why use `rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0)` when `transparent` offers the most cross browser support?

Comment: @cimmamon Because transparent alone was not working in ie8, and if all else fails i'd prefer the background display white. The bigger problem seems to be that ie10 is failing when transparent is in play.

Comment: IF the hacks for old IE are breaking modern IE (which supports the same code as other modern browsers), why don't you put the IE hacks in a conditional comment? That way IE10 won't get them.

Comment: @DAvid Storey because IE10 doesn't support conditional comments anymore, so it tries to do everything anyway

Comment: But IE10 doesn't need the code you're trying to feed it. As only IE9 and below need "background: transparent\9;" why not hide it from IE by putting it in a conditional comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I met the same issue, I think the issue is reflection of `IE8` hack

The best solutions is use suppurate css for IE8 with condition at the top which may not effect other version of IE :)

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

or you can try like this

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]> <html class="ie7"> <![endif]-->  
<!--[if IE 8]>     <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->  
<!--[if IE 9]>     <html class="ie9"> <![endif]-->  
<!--[if !IE]><!--> <html>             <!--<![endif]-->
```

the you can have suppurate code for dirrent versions

```
   .element {  
        background: red;  
    }  
    .ie7 .element {  
        background: blue;  
    }  
    .ie8 .element {  
        backgroundt: green;  
    }  
    .ie9 .element {  
        margin-left: yellow;  
    }
```